# Save a Google Form as PDF on a Drive's folder using Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf-generation

This is my first approach using Google Scripts so apologize if the question is too easy.

All the steps are explained here: [Hacking it: Generate PDFs from Google Forms](https://medium.com/swlh/hacking-it-generate-pdfs-from-google-forms-3ca4fcc5a0aa). I took the following image from there:

[image: What I have]

The code is posted on the link but I post it here anyways:

```
function onSubmit(e) { // From https://medium.com/swlh/hacking-it-generate-pdfs-from-google-forms-3ca4fcc5a0aa
  const rg = e.range;
  const sh = rg.getSheet();
  
  //Get all the form submitted data
  //Note: This data is dependent on the headers. If headers, are changed update these as well.
  const cName = e.namedValues['Client Name'][0];
  const cEmail = e.namedValues['Client Email'][0];
  const cAddress = e.namedValues['Client Address'][0];
  const cMobile = e.namedValues['Client Mobile'][0];
  const sendCopy = e.namedValues['Send client a copy?'][0];
  const paymentType = e.namedValues['What is your agreed upon payment schedule?'][0];
  const fixedCost = e.namedValues['What was your agreed upon cost for the project?'][0];
  const hourlyRate = e.namedValues['Hourly Rate'][0];
  const manHours = e.namedValues['Total man hours'][0];
  const services = e.namedValues['Select the services'][0];
  
  //Consequential Data
  const tax = 18.5
  var subtotal = 0;
  var taxAmt = 0;
  var payableAmt = 0;
      
  //if the user has selected hourly payment model
  //Note: Be careful that the responses match the elements on the actual form
  switch (paymentType ){
    case 'Hourly Rate':
      subtotal = hourlyRate*manHours;
      taxAmt = subtotal * (tax/100);
      payableAmt = +subtotal + +taxAmt;
      break;
    case 'Fixed Cost':
      subtotal = fixedCost;
      taxAmt = fixedCost * (tax/100)
      payableAmt = +fixedCost + +taxAmt;
      break;            
  }
  
  const invoiceID = 'IN' + Math.random().toString().substr(2, 9);
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "IST", "dd-MMM-yyyy");
  
  //Set the consequential data in the columns of the spreadsheet for record keeping
  //Note: These variable are dependent on the sheet's columns so if that changes, please update.
  const row = rg.getRow();
  
  const payableAmtCol = 2; //B
  const invoiceIDCol = 3; //C
  
  sh.getRange(row,payableAmtCol).setValue(payableAmt);
  sh.getRange(row,invoiceIDCol).setValue(invoiceID); 
  
  
  //Build a new invoice from the file
  //Folder and file IDs
  const invoiceFolderID = '<invoice-folder-id>';
  const invoiceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(invoiceFolderID);
  
  const templateFileID = '<template-id>';
  const newFilename = 'Invoice_' + invoiceID;
  
  //Make a copy of the template file
  const newInvoiceFileID = DriveApp.getFileById(templateFileID).makeCopy(newFilename, invoiceFolder).getId();;
  
  //Get the invoice body into a variable
  var document = DocumentApp.openById(newInvoiceFileID);
  var body = document.getBody();
  
  //Replace all the {{ }} text in the invoice body
  body.replaceText('{{Invoice num}}', invoiceID);
  body.replaceText('{{Date}}', formattedDate);
  body.replaceText('{{Client Name}}', cName);
  body.replaceText('{{Client Address}}', cAddress);
  body.replaceText('{{Client Mobile}}', cMobile);
  body.replaceText('{{Client Email}}', cEmail);
  body.replaceText('{{Services}}', services.split(', ').join('\n'));
  
  body.replaceText('{{Subtotal}}', subtotal);
  body.replaceText('{{Tax Value}}', taxAmt);
  body.replaceText('{{Total}}', payableAmt);
  
  //In the case of hourly rate payment type, let's add an additional message giving the rate and the man hours.
  if(paymentType.includes('Hourly Rate')){
     //It should look something like this on the invoice
     //Hourly Rate
     //Rate of Rs.1200/hour
     //Completed 50 man hours
     const message = paymentType + '\nRate of Rs.' + hourlyRate + '/hour\nCompleted ' + manHours + ' man hours';
     body.replaceText('{{Payment Type}}', message);
  } else {
    body.replaceText('{{Payment Type}}', paymentType);
  }
  
  document.saveAndClose();
  }
  
}
```

All the generated documents are saved in `Invoices` folder as `.docx`.

**Is there any way to edit the above code to save them as PDF?** Of course the PDF already had to be filled with the data provided in the Google Form, like the code does but they have to be saved as PDF, not `.docx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the getAs() to convert what you have saved as doc to pdf.

```
document.saveAndClose();
const blobPDF=document.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
const pdfFile=pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF);
```

This can only work if you save it to a folder. Suggestion below:

```
var pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(''); // insert your folder ID which you wish to store the pdf that was created.
```