# How to avoid requesting OAuth API verification to send emails using Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, authorization, sendmail

*This question comes from a previous one almost solved: [Save a Google Form as PDF on a Drive's folder using Google Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66862593/11617040)*

### Introduction

Perhaps this is a technical question and I am not programmer, so if possible I want a step-by-step answer so I can fully understand it.

The steps and purpose of the code are explained here: [Hacking it: Generate PDFs from Google Forms](https://medium.com/swlh/hacking-it-generate-pdfs-from-google-forms-3ca4fcc5a0aa).

The code is posted on the link but I post it here anyways:

```
function onSubmit(e) {
  const rg = e.range;
  const sh = rg.getSheet();
  
  //Get all the form submitted data
  //Note: This data is dependent on the headers. If headers, are changed update these as well.
  const cName = e.namedValues['Client Name'][0];
  const cEmail = e.namedValues['Client Email'][0];
  const cAddress = e.namedValues['Client Address'][0];
  const cMobile = e.namedValues['Client Mobile'][0];
  const sendCopy = e.namedValues['Send client a copy?'][0];
  const paymentType = e.namedValues['What is your agreed upon payment schedule?'][0];
  const fixedCost = e.namedValues['What was your agreed upon cost for the project?'][0];
  const hourlyRate = e.namedValues['Hourly Rate'][0];
  const manHours = e.namedValues['Total man hours'][0];
  const services = e.namedValues['Select the services'][0];
  
  //Consequential Data
  const tax = 18.5
  var subtotal = 0;
  var taxAmt = 0;
  var payableAmt = 0;
      
  //if the user has selected hourly payment model
  //Note: Be careful that the responses match the elements on the actual form
  switch (paymentType ){
    case 'Hourly Rate':
      subtotal = hourlyRate*manHours;
      taxAmt = subtotal * (tax/100);
      payableAmt = +subtotal + +taxAmt;
      break;
    case 'Fixed Cost':
      subtotal = fixedCost;
      taxAmt = fixedCost * (tax/100)
      payableAmt = +fixedCost + +taxAmt;
      break;            
  }
  
  const invoiceID = 'IN' + Math.random().toString().substr(2, 9);
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "IST", "dd-MMM-yyyy");
  
  //Set the consequential data in the columns of the spreadsheet for record keeping
  //Note: These variable are dependent on the sheet's columns so if that changes, please update.
  const row = rg.getRow();
  
  const payableAmtCol = 2; //B
  const invoiceIDCol = 3; //C
  
  sh.getRange(row,payableAmtCol).setValue(payableAmt);
  sh.getRange(row,invoiceIDCol).setValue(invoiceID); 
  
  
  //Build a new invoice from the file
  //Folder and file IDs
  const invoiceFolderID = '<invoice-folder-id>';
  const invoiceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(invoiceFolderID);
  
  const templateFileID = '<template-id>';
  const newFilename = 'Invoice_' + invoiceID;
  
  //Make a copy of the template file
  const newInvoiceFileID = DriveApp.getFileById(templateFileID).makeCopy(newFilename, invoiceFolder).getId();;
  
  //Get the invoice body into a variable
  var document = DocumentApp.openById(newInvoiceFileID);
  var body = document.getBody();
  
  //Replace all the {{ }} text in the invoice body
  body.replaceText('{{Invoice num}}', invoiceID);
  body.replaceText('{{Date}}', formattedDate);
  body.replaceText('{{Client Name}}', cName);
  body.replaceText('{{Client Address}}', cAddress);
  body.replaceText('{{Client Mobile}}', cMobile);
  body.replaceText('{{Client Email}}', cEmail);
  body.replaceText('{{Services}}', services.split(', ').join('\n'));
  
  body.replaceText('{{Subtotal}}', subtotal);
  body.replaceText('{{Tax Value}}', taxAmt);
  body.replaceText('{{Total}}', payableAmt);
  
  //In the case of hourly rate payment type, let's add an additional message giving the rate and the man hours.
  if(paymentType.includes('Hourly Rate')){
     //It should look something like this on the invoice
     //Hourly Rate
     //Rate of Rs.1200/hour
     //Completed 50 man hours
     const message = paymentType + '\nRate of Rs.' + hourlyRate + '/hour\nCompleted ' + manHours + ' man hours';
     body.replaceText('{{Payment Type}}', message);
  } else {
    body.replaceText('{{Payment Type}}', paymentType);
  }
  
  document.saveAndClose();
  
  /* This is not useful for me
  //If you have selected to directly send it via email
  if(sendCopy.includes('Yes')){
    //send email with the file
  var attachment = DriveApp.getFileById(newInvoiceFileID);
    GmailApp.sendEmail(cEmail, '<subject>, 
                     '<body>', 
                     {attachments: [attachment.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
                      from:'<your-email>@gmail.com'});
  }
  */
  
}
```

In the post, the author shows a way to send an Email to the client, which is what I want for my project.

### Actual problem

However, that portion of code is obsolete or the author has completed a verification process before she publishes her app because I have to request an OAuth API verification because of the `sendEmail` command. As I researched, it takes time and tools that I am completely unaware of (I'm not programmer).

Thus, I ask **if there is an easy way (without add-ons and avoid requesting a verification process) to send a copy of the generated document to the client when he press on "Send" button of Google Form based on the code I posted**.

The code works fine, it creates a copy of the document based on a template to a folder of my Drive, but I want to automate the sending of emails so that customers get a copy of the document that I have. I don't want to send any other information like spam etc.

*EDIT* This is the content I have inside `appsscript.json`:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Comment: GmailApp is part of the GSuite Core you should be able to use it unless you've been manually adding scopes to the manifest and then you may have to add `https://mail.google.com/`

Comment: @Cooper thanks for useful info! Could you explain in detail how I achieve what you say, please?

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: Search on Authorization Scopes in the Google Apps Documentation

Comment: @Cooper no reason; I had no idea about a new runtime engine. I just followed the steps of the link attached.

Comment: Never mind about the question about the runtime ... I was wrong

Comment: But what scopes do you have in your project

Comment: @Cooper I have `appsscript.json` (see updated question) and `Código.gs` which is the code I posted on the question. I also found this section inside my script project: https://imgur.com/RXrapY5 Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: It looks like you don't have the correct scopes.  I don't know why it didn't add it but you may have to do it manually then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's what one of my oauthscopes looks like:

```
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://mail.google.com/",
    "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects.readonly",
    "https://sites.google.com/feeds",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects"
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately it throws me a lot of required permissions :(. Content of `appsscript.json`: https://imgur.com/qYnT6y7 Last execution: https://imgur.com/8FGfkak What can we do?

Comment: Look now the list of areas requested: https://imgur.com/ao9PBeW Isn't it that I have "areas requested" which means I have to authenticate the permissions? Or am I wrong?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you use them all.  Just select the ones that you need.  It was just an example of how to write them.  You can't go through you life just mindlessly copying stuff you have to think.  Whether your a programmer or not.  Your in the game learn how to play it or get out.

Comment: I understand your comment and I apreciate the correction, but if I even leave only the minimum permissions the error message still appears and I do not receive any email.

Comment: Please update your code.  I don't see any GmailApp in your code.  Identify the line that's generating the error.

Comment: `GmailApp` is commented on the last lines of code because, if uncommented, it throws me the required permissions. P.S. I am trying with `@hotmail.com` domain. I have a GSuite account, maybe I can try with that account, as stated [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification#applicability).

Comment: Please update your code so that it represents your current version.

Comment: I will update the code soon, but I just tried with a GSuite account and it worked! I didn't even have to modify anything in `appsscript.json` (it does not have any `oauthScopes`). I suspect the problem I have is the Client verification of Google Scripts... The other Gmail account is "normal", so I must pass the whole process.

Comment: I started from scratch and it worked perfect, I have even received the emails from different types of Google accounts without any added scopes. Thanks again!!